# Access SQL "Where" Clause for Textbox on Form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm modifying the VBA code developed by someone else and am having difficulty adding a "Where" clause on a form.  As I'm a newbie to SQL I appreciate any assistance.

I have a table `tbl_FC_Data` which contains rows of data which present a forecast of part demand. It has over 43k records.  Each record is a forecast for a `Part_Number` for a `Data_Month` for a specific company (`Company_Code`) for a forecast provided on a specific date i.e. `Date_of_Forecast`.  Below is a table with a sample of the data.

```
Part_Number     Data_Month  Qty     Company_Code  Date_of_FC
AN565B8H4       1/1/2020    35      WAL2         12/11/2019
AN565B8H4       2/1/2020    1095    WAL2         12/11/2019
02-14-202-11    12/1/2019   20      D17          12/4/2019
02-14-202-11    1/1/2020    10      D17          12/4/2019
02-14-202-11    5/1/2020    1       D17          12/4/2019
02-14-202-11    6/1/2020    1       D17          12/4/2019
435W2151-49A    7/1/2020    40      API1         6/16/2020
02-14-202-11    6/1/2020    50      EAIL1        6/1/2020
02-14-202-11    7/1/2020    1       EAIL1        6/1/2020
02-14-202-11    1/1/2020    50      CZS1         12/19/2019
02-14-202-11    1/1/2020    50      CZS1         1/30/2020
```

The Access form contains two list boxes, the first which lists all the companies with data in the table (`lstCriteriaCompany`) and the second which contains the lists of forecasts dates for all records in the table (`lstCriteriaDate_Of_Fc`) regardless of company.

The existing VBA/SQL code to list all the forecast dates in the table is:

```
Me.lstCriteriaDate_Of_Fc.RowSource = "SELECT '#' & Format(D.Date_of_FC,'yyyy-mm-dd') & '#' AS IN_LIST_VALUE, " & _
                                               "Format(D.Date_of_FC,'mm/dd/yyyy') AS DATE_OF_FORECAST " & _
                                               "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC FROM tbl_FC_Data) AS D"
```

It produces the following list of forecast dates:

```
12/4/2019
12/11/2019
12/19/2019
1/30/2020
6/1/2020
6/16/2020
```

My goal is that when a user clicks on a company in the first textbox the `On Click` code (`Me.lstCriteriaDate_Of_Fc.RowSource = ...`) displays the list of forecasts that relate to the *selected* company in the first textbox.  For example, if CZS1 is selected then the textbox listing the forecasts would be changed to:

```
12/19/2019
1/30/2020
```

Here is where I added the `Where` clause.  It returns zero records instead of the two records I expected. When the code is executed a dialog box pops up and asks for the parameter value for `D.Company_Code`.

```
Me.lstCriteriaDate_Of_Fc.RowSource = "SELECT '#' & Format(D.Date_of_FC,'yyyy-mm-dd') & '#' AS IN_LIST_VALUE, " & _
                                               "Format(D.Date_of_FC,'mm/dd/yyyy') AS DATE_OF_FORECAST " & _
                                               "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC FROM tbl_FC_Data) AS D " & _
                                               "Where D.Company_Code= '" & Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Column(0) & "'"
```

I also tried `HAVING tbl_FC_Data.Company_Code = Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Value` but I get a SQL error.

Thanks for any SQL help you can provide.

Comment: You say "two text boxes" and "first textbox", do you mean "list" instead of text?

Comment: Yes it is a List Box. Sorry for the confusion @June7

Answer (score 0):

Referencing listbox selection is rather different from other data controls. Pull required value of selected item by referencing column by its index, even if value is in first column which would be index 0.

`Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Column(0)`

Concatenate this reference to the SQL string.

Comment: Actually I have to extract the `Company_Code` from the`lstCriteriaCompany` list box.  Thus my `WHERE` clause uses the string variable.

Comment: Reference whichever column you want by its index.

Comment: @June17 I can use `Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Column(0)` to access the `Company_Code`.  When I add `Where (D.Company_Code = Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Column(0))` to the end of the RowSource code I get zero records instead of the two I am expecting in the example above.

Comment: Concatenate variables. Reference to form control is a variable. Which column is Company_Code in? `"Where D.Company_Code ='" & Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Column(x) & "'"`

Comment: When I add the `Where` clause I get zero records returned.  I've added the code to the problem statement above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the `Where` clause needed to be part of the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause.  Here is the code that works:

```
Me.lstCriteriaDate_Of_Fc.RowSource = "SELECT '#' & Format(tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC,'yyyy-mm-dd') & '#' AS IN_LIST_VALUE, " & _
                                               "Format(tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC,'mm/dd/yyyy') AS DATE_OF_FORECAST " & _
                                               "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC FROM tbl_FC_Data " & _
                                               "Where tbl_FC_Data.Company_Code = " & Me.lstCriteriaCompany.Column(0) & ");"
```